# Aspose.Pdf bug in .Net C#. Table of Contents Title issue with Document.ProcessParagraphs()

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose

When creating a document with a Table of contents and a Title everything works great as below.

```
public void CreateTableOfContentsPage(TextFragment title)
{
    TOCPage = AddPage(this);
    TOCPage.TOCInfo = new TocInfo
    {
        Title = title,
        FormatArray = Array.Empty<LevelFormat>()
    };
}
```

When I add pageNumbering and add the Document.ProcessParagraphs();
The Table of Contents page title is duplicated below the table of contents
as below.

[PDF Table of Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZEXb.png)

This is corrected by removing the Document.ProcessParagraphs(), but then the Page numbers are screwed up.  This is a major issue, either you have a Table of contents or page numbers, but not both.

Aspose.Pdf for .Net is version 23.10.

I was expecting.
[Correct Table of Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QUwz.png)

Comment: Looks like the issue needs proper investigation. Would you please create a post in our official support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) with complete sample code snippet? We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. Please note that official support forum is the right place to discuss and post such topics. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.